# Name the Worksheet it's filename

Tags: excel, vba

I have been searching for the answer to this question and have found some helpful hints but can't make it work within this code.

I'm copying three tabs and the workbook's name is in Cover!R11 but the other two tabs from that file need the filename as well with an extension (i.e. Filename, Cover, Filename Summary, Filename Estimate). If I reference the cell with the filename when I'm on the second sheet, how can I reference the previous sheet?  That's why I thought it easier to use the Filename instead. I tried using: Sheets(SheetName1).Name = FilePath but I can't figure out how to trim it within this code.  Can you help?

Here's the code:

```
Sub CopySheets()
Dim DialogBox As FileDialog

Dim FilePath As String
Dim SheetName As String

Set DialogBox = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    DialogBox.Title = "Select Estimates to copy " & FileType
    DialogBox.AllowMultiSelect = True
    DialogBox.Filters.Clear
    DialogBox.Show

    If DialogBox.SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
       FilePath = DialogBox.SelectedItems(1)
    End If

For i = 1 To DialogBox.SelectedItems.Count

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

FilePath = DialogBox.SelectedItems(i)
SheetName1 = "Cover"
SheetName2 = "Summary"
SheetName3 = "Estimate and Schedule "
Set closedBook = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)

closedBook.Sheets(SheetName1).Copy 
After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)

Range("B2:Z97").Select
Selection.Copy
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="zxc"
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

'The file name I want to use is in this field, but I can't reference it for the other tabs. 
 Sheets(SheetName1).Name = Range("R11") 

closedBook.Sheets(SheetName2).Copy 
After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)

Range("B5:K39").Select
Selection.Copy
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="zxc"
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Range("D1").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
 Application.CutCopyMode = False


'This line here didn't work to pull the previous sheet's value in R11
'Sheets(SheetName2).Name = prevname.Range("R11") & "Summary"


closedBook.Sheets(SheetName3).Copy 
After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)

Range("A3:M70").Select
Selection.Copy
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="zxc"
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

closedBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You can get the name of the workbook you open using `closedWorkbook.Name`.

Comment: I changed the code to: Sheets(SheetName1).Name = closedBook.Name and I got a Run-time error 1004 because it's using the entire path name.  this was my original issue when just using FilePath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the value from 'Cover'!R11 later in the code store it in a variable.

```vb
'The file name I want to use is in this field, but I can't reference it for the other tabs. 
Dim strFilename As String
    ' other code

    strFilename = Sheets("Cover").Range("R11").Value

    Sheets(SheetName1).Name = strFilename

    ' more code
    Sheets(SheetName2).Name = strFilename & " Summary"

    ' even more code
    Sheets(SheetName2).Name = strFilename & " Estimate"
```

Comment: That was awesome!!